# comprei um site mas não sei como instalar. [nginx, laravel, linux]

Tags: laravel, linux, nginx

o site é nginx laravel, se fosse apache eu até saberia.

isso que vem escrito, mas não diz os comandos que tenho que dar na vps para instalar isso e tals:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja se [esse link](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=acbr_nfedanferl.bpl+nao+pode+ser+encontrado&oq=acbr_nfedanferl.bpl+nao+pode+ser+encontrado&aqs=chrome..69i57.3890j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=install+nginx+linux+php) ajuda.

Comment: O que exatamente vc quer fazer? Tem acesso ssh ao servidor?

Comment: sim tenho acesso ssh.

Comment: Troque para apache no servidor. A aplicação não depende da sua infra, pode usar IIS, Windows... que a aplicação irá funcionar